# How to write code to close the current open Notebook document after 10 seconds?

Tags: notebooks, scheduledtask

How to write code to close the current open Notebook document after 10 seconds?

```
SessionSubmit[ScheduledTask[NotebookClose[], Quantity[10, "Seconds"]]]
```

I expected the above execution, but it is not. What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your task is held and executed asynchronously so once it gets to the Kernel it won't 'remember' which notebook it was sent from. You need to send it with that information:

```
With[{nb = EvaluationNotebook[]}, 
 SessionSubmit[ScheduledTask[NotebookClose@nb, Quantity[10, "Seconds"]]]
 ]
```

Comment: I solved it using 'SessionTime'. The answer is excellent, too! Thank you!

Dynamic[ 
 If[Floor[SessionTime[]] > 600, NotebookClose[], 
  Row[{ Floor@SessionTime[], "/600"}]  ], UpdateInterval -> 1]